# how to store and load a list to and from a file in python, while retaining its element type

Tags: python, list

if i store objects in a list.
and i want this list to be stored in a file, in such a way that this list, when loaded from the file. It must contain same characteristics as before it saved, like element type.

Comment: You can use the `pickle` module for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pickle` for this, e.g :

```
import pickle
my_list = [1,2,3]
pickle.dump( my_list, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
my_list = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

This will save the type and value of your object. More information about pickle usage can be found here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html